# Screensaver making software now that flash is unsupported

Tags: windows-10

Before the support for adobe Flash in Windows 10 has ended, there has been a very neat software [Instantstorm](https://instantstorm.com/download/) that could create screensavers from swf files. The advantage of this software over anything else is that it made use of flash engine and could export very lightweight vector animations via help of flash libraries that were packed along with the screensaver in the exe file.

However, Windows has ended support for Flash in december 2020 and the only paid/free software that i have found are only simple wrappers that export videos and the file sizes are huge, the video is compressed and there are no vector based animations. (even very expensive ones like [this one](https://aescripts.com/screen-saver-exporter/) are just video wrappers)

Is there still some either paid or free software that could export screensavers efficiently in vector formats, and not just some video wrapper?

Comment: It seems there are SWF to HTML5 converter - none of which I have tried. I have written a screensaver in .NET that shows a HTML website. Maybe if we combine these two concepts, we get there. You could try converting a SWF to HTML5 and check that it works. Send me the resulting HTML code and I'll try whether it works in my screensaver.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that'd be cool! here is a demo flash animation exported into javascript https://github.com/verybigelephants/demo-flash-html-export